# BufferedReader infinite loop

Tags: java

I'm getting an infinite loop error but I don't know how to end the loop.

```
int a,b,c;
String line;
     
BufferedReader  br  =  new  BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(System.in));
 
while((line=br.readLine())!=null);    
{
    System.out.println("Enter the two numbers to add:");
    a=Integer.parseInt(line);
    b=Integer.parseInt(line);
    c = a+b;
    System.out.println("Sum of two numbers:"+ c);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int a, b, c;
    String line;

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter the two numbers to add:");
        if ((line = br.readLine()) != null && !line.isBlank()) {
            String[] input = line.split(" ");
            a = Integer.parseInt(input[0]);
            b = Integer.parseInt(input[1]);
            c = a + b;
            System.out.println("Sum of two numbers:" + c);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    } while (true);
}
```

Output:

```
Enter the two numbers to add:
4 5
Sum of two numbers:9
Enter the two numbers to add:
```

Comment: You are awesome! and you're so great! this is correct. Now I'm studying the lists and arrays as well as looping on lists and arrays number which is so hard but will work it out :D

Comment: Would be great if you accept one of the answers and give up votes to encourage people.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `;` from the end of the while loop because now you code is like

while loop without body

```
while((line=br.readLine())!=null);
```

and code block

```
{
    System.out.println("Enter the two numbers to add:");
    a=Integer.parseInt(line);
    b=Integer.parseInt(line);
    c = a+b;
    System.out.println("Sum of two numbers:"+ c);
}
```

So the code will stay in the while loop forever and just read lines

Note: a and b will convert the same line to int if your line like 10 20 you need to split it into 2 string first then get every integer in the variable

```
String[] number = line.split(" ");
a=Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
b=Integer.parseInt(numbers[1]);
```

or you can use Scanner to read integer by integer for example

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    int a = scanner.nextInt();
    int b = scanner.nextInt();
    int c = a+b;
    System.out.println("Sum of two numbers:"+ c);
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your response to this one. tbh I'm clueless on how to fix it when I removed the semicolon I'm getting another error of no numbers being entered. anyway, should I follow the code blocked that you've commented on?

Comment: I recommend you to try to play with the Scanner class and also learn about try-catch to handle cases when the user enters a string or non-number, and keep your BufferedReader for interact with files

Comment: Thanks, I will do that. thanks a lot for this one. appreciate it

Comment: I did the scanner bro however I am really adamant to do it in the buffered reader. can you help me with this one?

Comment: Very nice, I think the other answer provides good examples and you can explore more examples here https://www.javatpoint.com/java-bufferedreader-class

Comment: thanks a lot. this really means a lot to me

Answer (score 0):

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class InfLoop {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        example1();
        example2();
    }

    private static void example1() {
        try (InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);) {

            while (true) {
                final String line1 = br.readLine();
                if (line1 == null) {
                    System.out.println("First number not entered! Aborting...");
                    break;
                }

                final String line2 = br.readLine();
                if (line2 == null) {
                    System.out.println("Second number not entered! Aborting...");
                    break;
                }

                final int number1 = Integer.parseInt(line1);
                final int number2 = Integer.parseInt(line2);
                final int c = number1 + number2;
                System.out.println("Result of '" + number1 + "'+'" + number2 + "'='" + c + "'");
            }

        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void example2() throws IOException {
        try (InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);) {

            while (true) {
                final Integer number1 = readInteger(br, "Enter first number: ");
                if (number1 == null) {
                    System.out.println("First number is invalid! Aborting...");
                    break;
                }

                final Integer number2 = readInteger(br, "Enter second number: ");
                final String line2 = br.readLine();
                if (line2 == null) {
                    System.out.println("Second number is invalid! Aborting...");
                    break;
                }

                final int c = number1.intValue() + number2.intValue();
                System.out.println("Sum of '" + number1 + "'+'" + number2 + "'='" + c + "'");
            }
        }
    }

    private static Integer readInteger(final BufferedReader pBr, final String pMessage) {
        if (pMessage != null) System.out.println(pMessage);
        try {
            final String line = pBr.readLine();
            if (line == null) return null;

            return Integer.valueOf(line);

        } catch (final Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
/*
 * 1) indentation was off, use IDE that does formatting for you
 * 2) use try/resource(/catch/finally)
 * 3) you need to read 2 separate lines, else a and b are the same
 * 4) start using helper methods (readInteger), save you lots of duplicate code
 * 5) there's two different ways of error handling here: handle inside the method (example1), or throw (example2),
 *    whatever is more useful for the calling code
 * 6) usually handling errors (instead of throwing them) should only be done if it is a direct requirement to the method!
 */
```

/UPDATE: changed IOException to Exception in readInteger()

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. I will explore more on this one. thanks a lot, sir

Comment: Oh I just saw I made a mistake... in `readInteger()` I wrote `catch(IOException e)`. I corrected it to  `catch (Exception e)` so that all Exceptions - especially the parse Exception - returns a `null` to indicate invalid values

Comment: you are awesome! How I wish I never stop coding.

Comment: I learned the hard way that at some (very early) point, only practice can really teach you. So keep going ;-)

Comment: Yes, you're right sir. I will keep on going and thanks a lot for all of your ideas and inputs. this helps me a lot.